# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:In jaspereports in struts2

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports

Trying to integrate jasperreports with struts2....and i am very new to jasperreports ....designed reports using eclipse report designer

here is my jrmxlЖ

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.0  -->
<!-- 2015-08-24T16:05:04 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Coffee_Landscape" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="df013db5-f76e-44d3-b0df-bcbc46d93160">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Title" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#736343" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#E6DAC3"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <field name="transaction_Date" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="amount_Of_Sale" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="discount_Amount" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="136" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="164" height="126" uuid="1c003177-754c-448f-8ce1-16868856f545"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["pctv-blue-rect.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Title" x="190" y="0" width="443" height="62" uuid="bc1ce1da-8232-46ea-be55-cec4abb986dd"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[MyFirstJasper]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="SubTitle" x="303" y="62" width="196" height="22" uuid="f6a78448-8260-4445-a9e0-e3fb53b080d9"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Coffee SubTitle]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="172" y="94" width="383" height="42" uuid="8240065e-64b6-4170-b5d9-6341598e7b35"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor purus gravida arcu aliquam mattis. Donec et nulla libero, ut varius massa. Nulla sed turpis elit. Etiam aliquet mauris a ligula hendrerit in auctor leo lobortis.]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="15" width="802" height="1" uuid="e9d2002a-c8ee-4649-a258-640dad29110c"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="0" y="0" width="267" height="15" forecolor="#736343" uuid="732f1c0f-9a82-40f6-a3ec-adc1a7974b20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[TRANSACTION DATE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="267" y="0" width="267" height="15" forecolor="#736343" uuid="3d530dc4-b1f1-4fc8-97a9-caf5e9880788"/>
                <text><![CDATA[AMOUNT OF SALE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="534" y="0" width="267" height="15" forecolor="#736343" uuid="79cddcd9-d19c-4737-bef4-4f5913c70e06"/>
                <text><![CDATA[DISCOUNT AMOUNT]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement style="Row" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="15" uuid="fa7cec56-4ec1-48e6-a26e-7266a995d174"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" x="0" y="0" width="267" height="15" uuid="8af81006-b893-4305-b756-5393650dbe47"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{transaction_Date}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" x="267" y="0" width="267" height="15" uuid="0b740c0b-0299-4454-b6d1-98fba48bd8d1"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount_Of_Sale}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="Detail" x="534" y="0" width="267" height="15" uuid="135c7c39-45d3-4b00-a67e-58caf29dc186"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{discount_Amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="6" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="3" width="802" height="1" uuid="fa5e88d5-a011-4e32-8f12-ce923f903111"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-21" y="1" width="843" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#F2EBDF" uuid="5d8169bd-4a75-48c8-8a68-6d3ad5ba9402"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="783" y="1" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="e5e27efa-b599-499b-9ca3-848cb511cb7b"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="703" y="1" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="18cfe1ca-f7d6-48b0-9827-28578b42a5e0"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="1" y="1" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="fbce24bb-3cb1-44a3-8eec-8c067ddbe5b5"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

And Struts.xml

```
<action name="myJasperTest" class="com.pincodetv.jasper.JasperAction">
        <result name="success" type="jasper">
            <param name="location">/jasper/our_compiled_template.jasper</param>
            <param name="dataSource">myList</param>
            <param name="format">PDF</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Jars which i have in lib

```
struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.2.3.jar
jasperreports-6.1.0.jar
jasperreports-fonts-6.1.0.jar
jasperreports-javaflow-6.1.0.jar
```

The error logs...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult.doExecute(JasperReportsResult.java:321)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: @AleksandrM its working with jasperreports-4.1.0.jar thanks...

Comment: @people Y downVote...??

Answer (score 1):

i got the same problem, i used struts2, jasper-report 5.6.0, japer report library 5.6.0. how i solved my problem is just added class JRLoader download here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/4.5.0/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRLoader.java

add the joda library in you project library,
joda download here:
https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases/download/v2.9.4/joda-time-2.9.4-dist.tar.gz

create package in you project net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util
and put the JRLoader.java in that package, then run your project
viola.... it's work....